# PHP Regex match url path

Tags: php, regex

I have a url in the following formats

```
/fixed1/term1/fixed2/term2
/fixed1/term1/term2/fixed2/term3
/fixed1/term1/term2/...termN.../fixed2/termN+1
```

in all cases I need the regex to return me all the terms (not including the fixedN).
term can be anything (as long as it's a valid url)

I managed to get until

```
fixed1\/([^\/]+)\/fixed2\/(.*)
```

which works fine for

```
/fixed1/term1/fixed2/term2
```

but does not work properly on the other cases (when I have multiple terms between the two fixed words)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not `explode('/', $path)` and then remove the `fixedN` from the resultant array if it is present?

Comment: While `explode` seems to be the ultimate solution, if you still want to play with your regexp, you are to move straight slash out of square brackets: `(([^/]/)+)`.

Answer (score 0):

your regex

```
[^\/]+
```

will stop after it hits the first backslash, which is why you can find term1 just fine.  As a lazy first stab at this solution, i would try

```
fixed1\/(.+?)\/fixed2\/(.*)
```